# Use JS + Simple SKU to lookup configurable sku

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, ecommerce-tracking, google-tag-manager

I'm setting up enhanced ecommerce tracking using GTM for our site & a problem I'm running into is product lists & product details output the config sku to the dataLayer but adds to cart, checkouts, and transactions output the simple sku to the dataLayer.

I want this to be uniform so that all of these events output the config sku to the dataLayer.

Is there a way for me to use the simple SKU & javascript to look up a simple sku's config sku & pass that to GTM instead of the built-in simple sku value? Or is backend work required for this?

(Using 2.3.2)